# Backend test automation framework - Java

Tags: automated-testing, java

I'd like to create and ask about best framework for backend end-to-end tests.
This is microservice architecture software and the services communicates via REST API and Apache Kafka.
What would be best frameworks/libraries for such technologies? The most important is reliability and interoperability of the system.

Comment: "the best" is not an objective measurement here, otherwise there would be only one in the market. What is your context? What quality attributes are important for your context?

Comment: Good point @JoãoFarias. The most important is relability and interoperability

Comment: Have you tried postman ?

Comment: @PDHide - yes, but I want to do the automation framework, and there is also Apache Kafka so I think it doesn't support it

Comment: Do not know much about Kafka. Can you show us how you perform manual testing for some GET (or similar) request. But for the rest you can use restasshured, and Postman as some previous comments are displayed. See also https://dzone.com/articles/a-quick-and-practical-example-of-kafka-testing ,maybe you will catch something there.

Comment: using java for handling json is over complicated . For rest api i would prefer javascript or python based framework like postman , robotframework etc . As they can handle json well

Comment: Postman is used test autoamtion not just for manual. But i am not sure about kafka

Answer (score 1):

Start by deciding on the "what" and later solve the "how".

Your overall testing should follow the test pyramid with slight modifications due to the complexity of such a system. Some of the best reading material about it is [Martin Fowler, Testing Strategies in a Microservice Architecture](https://martinfowler.com/articles/microservice-testing/)  and  [Cindy Sridharan, Testing Microservices, the sane way](https://copyconstruct.medium.com/testing-microservices-the-sane-way-9bb31d158c16).

Another good source is [from PACT, Introduction to Microservices Testing and Consumer Driven Contract Testing with PACT](https://www.novatec-gmbh.de/en/blog/introduction-microservices-testing-consumer-driven-contract-testing-pact/).

To summarize the sources, they basically say that the focus in the test pyramid should move slightly up. For example you should still invest in good old unit tests but also remember that in a Micro Services environment they are even less beneficial in finding system problems.